# How do you make your Google Colab code trusted in my personal github?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

How do I make my google Colab trusted in my github? Because my file isn't trusted, none of my maps are displayed. I know Jupyter Notebook has a button for it. Is there a way to make it so that my file is trusted in github?

[image: Github File output]

Comment: You aren't guaranteed that will work even if it is set to trust. You are better off treating GitHub's rendering of Jupyter Notebooks as solely rough previews meant for you and other coders. For better viewing and an interface not off-putting to the general public, use the solution by the Jupyter community, [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/). Just go there and put in your GitHub URL. If your notebook is private use [notebook{sharing}.space](https://words.yuvi.in/post/announcing-notebooksharing-space/) which are private by default. **Not sure it will help here because you don't provide a MRE.**

Comment: As evidence, look at the plot from the cell [2] [in nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/orca-plotly-binderized/blob/master/index.ipynb) and hover over some of the points and notice information pops up. The [same notebook at Github(actually what nbviewer is rendering)](https://github.com/fomightez/orca-plotly-binderized/blob/master/index.ipynb) shows no plot even for the second cell. There's at least four other issues still. Knowing used to be less of an issue because GitHub would only try to preview tiny notebooks & so most people learned fast it was only a quick preview.